# Android L transition and home up button

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I am using the new Android L transition, in particular shared element transitions along with a Slide(). When I press the back button the transitions work perfectly, it slides and transitions the shared ImageView to the correct spot but when I press the home-up button in the ActionBar it ignores the new transitions.

I set this block of code in the receiving activity:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Slide());
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Slide());
```

And this block of code in my 'Main' Activity:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    Transition transition = new Slide();
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
    getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(transition);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you call `finishAfterTransition()` when the action bar's up button is clicked:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finishAfterTransition();             
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Of course I call finish(). The problem still persists, it does not do the same animation.

Comment: @MaxKleine Sorry, my original answer had a typo. I meant `finishAfterTransition()`, _not_ `finish()`. I've edited my post with the correction.